# Atmosphere Websockets over HTTPS

Tags: http, nginx, https, websocket, atmosphere

I have used Atmosphere based web sockets to develop a multi chat room and it is working fine over HTTP connection. However, when I try to use HTTPS based connection, it fails.

I have used Atmosphere's Simple Broadcaster strategy and on debugging have found that it does enter @OnReady function.
However, the broadcaster connection is aborted soon and hence no code execution happens in @OnMessage.
I have deployed the app on AWS and have opened the necessary ports.
I have used nginx in between. Websocket configuration for nginx has been set. 
Following is the code for same.

```
            # WebSocket support

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Is there something else we need to do to allow websocket response from HTTPS?

Comment: Is the SSL Cert configuration correct ? I mean does it need trusted certificate etc ? This should be done on Nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same issue when run my application as *.jar* but when I
changed the application and runs it at *.war*  it worked fine.

Though I am not sure why there was an issue to run the application as *.jar* , but you can give it a try.